# Get a row of a pandas DataFrame as a dict-like object with correct types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

As suggested in [Get a row of data in pandas as a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823596/850781), one can extract a row from a `pandas` `DataFrme` using `loc`:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1.0,"b":2,"c":3}]).set_index("c")
df1.loc[3].to_dict()
```

returns `{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0}` - alas, this is ***wrong*** because the `b` value should be `2` and not `2.0`.

**How do I extract a row with correct types?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use `[[]]` for one row `DataFrame`, a bit ovecomplicated in my opinion:

```
d = df1.loc[[3]].to_dict(orient='record')[0]
print (d)
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2}
```

Problem is if create Series by `loc` (`df1.loc[3]`) then `float` column upcast integer(s) columns.

Comment: Wow! Behold the ugliness! ;-) And it works around [anther problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67436529/850781) too!